# Hotel Room Listing in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to build hotel room booking management system using Laravel.

Problem  in retrieving room available based on the user search in the portal

Hotel has many rooms and rooms has many tariff based on the date. I need all the room tarrif based on the check in and check out date. But i am getting all the records which are there in database between that days. I want only the room which are available on all the days.

Example: 
User is searching hotel from 19-11-2019 to  22-11-2019. But some hotel inventory are not there on 21-11-2019. But i am getting that records.I want the records which are available on all the days.(i.e 19-11-2019,20-11-2019,21-11-2019,22-11-2019)

```
HotelPriceDetail::where('room_id',$value->room_id)
                  ->whereBetween('hotel_price_details.date',[$check_in,$check_out])
                  ->where('hotel_price_details.inventory','>=',$total_adults)
                  ->get();
```

Can any one suggest me what i need to change in my code.

Comment: So how can we evaluate hotel inventory? for that any particular column in the database. Which indicates hotel inventory available or not? Please explain more.

Comment: inventory column is holding the number of rooms available on that particular date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you dump your $check_in and $check_out variables? I'm not sure if your date format is correct. It should be something like this

```
$from = date('2019-11-19');
$to = date('2019-11-22');

HotelPriceDetail::whereBetween('hotel_price_details.date', [$from, $to])->get();
```

Comment: I am able to retrieve the data using the given query but i am getting all the record between that date . I want the data where that particular room_id  is available in all the days.